# Parsing Ajax response using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

1. I have a php function, which generates calendar for the current
   month with button for next and previous months.
2. I also have a js file, which monitors the click event and generates calendar for next or
   previous month.
3. I am fetching the calendar data from the php function (as defined in step 1) using ajax function.

On clicking the button, I observe all the previous/next month calendar data in my console log but don't know how to parse the data to update the current page with latest calendar data.

My js code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery('#prev_button_id').click(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: frontend_object.plugin_url_info + '/includes/previous_month.php',
            success: (response)=>{
                console.log(response);
            },
            error:(response)=>{
           console.log("prev month not loaded");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My Console output for previous month calendar

```
 <table class='calendar'>
<div class = 'month_block'
><input id='prev_button_id' class='prev_button' type='button' value = '&#8249 Previous'/>
<div class = 'month'>April 2020</div>
<a class='next_button' href='TBD'>Next &#8250</a>
</div><tr><th class='header'>S</th><th class='header'>M</th><th class='header'>T</th><th class='header'>W</th><th class='header'>T</th><th class='header'>F</th><th class='header'>S</th></tr><tr><td colspan='3'>&nbsp;</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-01'>1</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-02'>2</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-03'>3</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-04'>4</td></tr><tr><td class='day' rel='2020-04-05'>5</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-06'>6</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-07'>7</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-08'>8</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-09'>9</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-10'>10</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-11'>11</td></tr><tr><td class='day' rel='2020-04-12'>12</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-13'>13</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-14'>14</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-15'>15</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-16'>16</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-17'>17</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-18'>18</td></tr><tr><td class='day' rel='2020-04-19'>19</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-20'>20</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-21'>21</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-22'>22</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-23'>23</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-24'>24</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-25'>25</td></tr><tr><td class='day' rel='2020-04-26'>26</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-27'>27</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-28'>28</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-29'>29</td><td class='day' rel='2020-04-30'>30</td><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Exactly what HTML does `previous_month.php` return?

Comment: @kmoser, previous_month.php is returning previous month calendar details. I pasted the exact response (see console output in the main question) that function returns. I need to understand, how you can extract data from this response and update your current page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to replace the current `.calendar` with the new HTML returned by the AJAX call:

```
success: (response) => {
    $('.calendar').replaceWith( response );
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed but just need minor tweak. Above code is replacing the entire calendar except the contents inside  div class = 'month_block'. Not sure why this is happening. Now I have unexpected text "<Previous May 2020 Next>", then expected entire April month calendar. @kmoser

Comment: There was an issue with my html structure, I fixed it. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @kmoser.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the element that the calendar is in and setting its .innerHTML value to the output:

```
element.innerHTML = response;
```

If the calendar is in an element with other elements, you could remove the calendar and use the += operator to add it to the end, or make a div for the calendar.

Comment: I tried "console.log(jQuery('.calendar').innerHTML);" but doesnt seem to be working. I got "undefined" on console log

Comment: That's because `.innerHTML` doesn't work with objects returned by jQuery. See my answer for a possible solution.

Comment: @Learner That is probably because you are replacing the calendar's (I assume .calendar is the calendar) innerHTML. Instead, the calendar needs to be inside a div, which you replace its innerHTML. Think of innerHTML as the code within an element. However, kmoser 's answer looks like it would work better. I don't use JQuery much myself.